# Wordpress-: Ignore 100% width container on posts and certain pages

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I changed my wordpress website's width from 1068px to 100%
as to have my homepage en blogpage display nicely.
Now the problem is that my posts and future playlist page don't act the way I want on 100% width.
It would be better if these pages still had 1068px.

Every page runs the same Td-Container and I would like to be able to ignore the 100% rule on certain pages.

Is this possible? Or will I have to style the inner containers back with margins and custom widths to look the same?

[Website](http://breakline.nl)

Comment: If it's a well-designed theme, your `body` element gets a class assigned to it depending on the page you are on, the page template, etc.  Take a look at the body class, you **probably** want to change your 100% width rules to **only** be on the home and blog listing page(s): `.body .td-container {width:100%;}`....  (NOTE: This question WILL get downvoted / closed if you don't show your code!)

Comment: I wouldn't change the 1068 to 100% only for some pages for the sake of consistency. Either all or none imho.

Comment: @cale_b Thank you! You got me in the right direction. Adressing the td-container from the body class home or a page-id helped me style it exactyle how I wanted.

Comment: @JonasGrumann The Homepage is full width, the post page is also full width but I dont like reading all the way to the left of my screen. I could have fixed that with margins but since it only changed to that way because of the full width property I was wondering if there was a fix.